# Macbook 5,5 with Ubuntu 17.10 freezes when exfat drive is connected

Tags: 17.10, macbook-pro, exfat

I had already installed the exfat-fuse earlier when I had first set up the laptop. After using the drive with macOS for a bit, Ubuntu would begin to freeze as soon as the drive would recognize.

Comment: If would be useful to have some details about your setup. Does the drive appear in your /etc/fstab file? If so, what is the entry?

Comment: @Jeremy here is my fstab. i have no idea what it means. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uTuupLk70Y7o5VfgEVYJefeTGUHrjtl5wkZAqWlU6G4/edit?usp=sharing. it was too long to put here

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I'll explain a little better. Please open up a terminal and type `sudo cat /etc/fstab` and post the results in the question. The fstab file is the file that tells the OS which disk partitions to expect to see and some details about how to handle them.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cbu8lpANrQeZv7zb2sUHq7cL4_urwLOyCyHJPWuRseA/edit?usp=sharing here it is. as far as i can tell its the same with 2 mores zeros